# mobile app auto dial on message from server

Tags: java, java-me

How do I autodial a mobile using a j2me app running on it based on a message initiated from a remote server.
The server message could trigger the j2me app to dial a predefined number.
I have figured out that the dialing can be done with the platformRequest() method through which I can send it a phonenumber as a url string.

However I dont know of any protocols where the server side can initiate dialogue with the client(j2me app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either get your server to send an SMS to the handset or have the j2me app maintain an open http dialog with the server.

In the second case, you will face issues related to auto-starting the j2me app, keeping it in the background until it is needed, battery drain...

Edit: The PushRegistry system will work with SMS but operators tend to block non-http traffic and using a tcp push system means finding a way to let the server know about the handset IP address and open port. SMS is the only true push mechanism used in practice.

Comment: I read about the pushregistry
(http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/pushreg/) and it says that tcp and udp conncections have been added in MIDP2.0 spec. Any idea how to a server can initiate an inbound TCP connection?!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible - for security and privacy reasons. However, as suggest above, the only way you could get it to work is from the J2ME application.

You could either let it listen for an SMS from a particular phone number and send off an event, or run a timer app in the background as suggest above. There you have it - those are your only options am afraid.